# Error in code, programming in C

Tags: c, codeblocks, scanf

I am writing a small little program as practice: its suppose to add vectors.
I get an error from the IDE stating that:" error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector." 
This occurs when I am going through a for loop and having the user input some data of type float, using the scanf() function. I will post the code below so you can see for yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    float xcomp;
    float ycomp;

}vectors;

vectors initializeVector(vectors userVect, int length);


int main()
{


     /* This block determines the amount of vectors that will be added.
    It will then create an array of vector structs the size of the amount being added.
    Afterwards it will call a function that will grab the users data (vector information) and use
    to add the vectors in the array.*/


    int amount;
    printf("How many vectors would you like to add?\n");
    printf("AMOUNT: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    vectors myvect[amount];


    initializeVector(myvect[amount],amount); //<-- This is a function call.
    return 0;

}


vectors initializeVector(vectors userVect, int length)
{
/* This function will go through the array of vectors and allow the user
to input the components of each vector in the array.*/

printf("Enter the 'X' and 'Y' components of your vector\n");
int i;
for(i=0; i<length;i++)
{
    printf("%d", i+1);
    printf(" vector:\n");
    printf("X: ");
    scanf("%f", userVect[i].xcomp); // This line brings up the error
    printf("\nY: ");
    scanf("%f", userVect[i].ycomp); //  this line brings up the error


    }



}
```

Comment: Why tagging [tag:c++] then? Re-Tagged ...

Comment: vectors *userVect; userVect[i]->xcomp;

Comment: Because "userVect" parameter is not an array.   You can't index it.

Comment: Your code is formatted hideously!

Comment: -1 for: failure to fully describe the issue, failure to describe what you've tried to fix it and a horrible question title

Comment: Why do you mean my code is formatted hideously?

Comment: Also, what does down voting do to me? Will it ban me from this site?

Comment: @Alberto93 you might want to [read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and about [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate an array of vectors, using malloc.

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
}vectors;

vectors initializeVector(vectors userVect[], int length);

int main()
{
    /* This block determines the amount of vectors that will be added.
    It will then create an array of vector structs the size of the amount being added.
    Afterwards it will call a function that will grab the users data (vector information) and use
    to add the vectors in the array.*/

    int amount;
    printf("How many vectors would you like to add?\n");
    printf("Count: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    if(amount<1) { printf("error, need vector size %d > 0\n",amount); exit(1); }
    vectors *vectarray = malloc(sizeof(vectors)*amount); //allocate the vector for the given vector size
    if(!vectarray) { printf("error, cannot allocate vectorarray[%d]\n",amount); exit(2); }
    initializeVector(vectarray,amount); //<-- This is a function call.
    return 0;
}
```

Then you need to pass that array (as a pointer) to the initializer, and you need to provide the address of your x,y components, not just the components.

```
vectors initializeVector(vectors userVect[], int length) //pass an array
{
    /* This function will go through the array of vectors and allow the user
    to input the components of each vector in the array.*/

    printf("Enter the 'X' and 'Y' components of your vector\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i+1);
        printf(" vector:\n");
        printf("X: ");
        scanf("%f", &(userVect[i].x)); //scanf wants a pointer to the x component
        printf("\nY: ");
        scanf("%f", &(userVect[i].y)); //scanf wants a pointer to the y component
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to decipher this and see what I get

Answer (score 0):

You cannot statically allocate an array by passing a variable (amount) as its size. In order to do this, you need to allocate it dynamically by using [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/?kw=malloc).
Furthermore, indexes in arrays are 0 based. This means that you can access its elements from 0 to size-1. If you pass myvector[size] you try to read after the last array element.

Comment: I am pretty new to writing code which means I am new to this technical language. If I understand you correctly, you are saying I cannot create an array of a certain size by using a variable to declare the size??

Comment: You cannot use a variable because when you statically allocate an array, its size must be determined at compile time. This means that when you build your executable, the compiler reserves a specific amount of memory to it. Since in your program the array size will be determined at runtime, you need to allocate it dynamically.